# ASIHTTPRequest how to recognize finished request and failed request?

Tags: objective-c

In my application, i have a button wich calls an ASIHTTPRequest. The request goes fine and i receive an response string. But when the request finishes, it always goes to the method: requestFinished. And i also got a requestFailed method. But even when i give a wrong link, the request finsihes and never fails.. Why is this? This is my code:

```
-(void)fetchForm:(id)sender {

    NSURL *URL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.nl/testGet.php"]; 
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL] autorelease];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Request Success!");
}

-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed!");
}
```

EDIT:

I read a little documentation on the ASIHTTPRequest website. And i came to the conclusion that i need to see for myself if there is an error code. i do this with:

```
int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];

if (statusCode == 404) {
NSLog(@"Statuscode 404 has occured!");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several conditions that might affect error reporting with HTTP requests. From ASIHTTP's viewpoint, if the request object can be successfully built, sent, and a some kind of response is received, then everything is ok.

In my case, for example, my ISP has a proxy that will return an error page with many not existing URLs and sometimes even with ill-formed URLs. In such cases, ASIHTTP will not fail. I don't know if this is also your case, but it was for me.

If you look at the file `ASIHTTPRequest.m` and search for `failWithError`, you will see all the cases where ASIHTTP will trigger the mechanism that leads to the `didFailSelector` to be called. You might even set a breakpoint in the `failWithError` method to see if it is called.

EDIT:

In a sense ASIHTTPRequest mechanism is very basic and covers failures at the *network* level. If you receive a response then it is an application level failure and you have to deal with it.

First thing is checking the HTTP status code:

```
int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
NSString *statusMessage = [request responseStatusMessage];
```

This will allow you to identify 404, 500, and so on.

If this does not work and the server does not send an error code, then the only way to go about it is parsing the response you receive and, if it does not contain the data you were waiting for, fail.

Comment: In my case, it is kind of the same. The request could be made, but the response is some kind of errorstring. But because of the returned errorstring, ASIHTTPRequest tought all went fine because something got returned. How do i change this?

Comment: It is just an 404 error if i call the url in the browser. And it comes from a PHP page.

Comment: You could implement UIWebViewDelegate protocol to catch adresses and deal with this page

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i don't know how to do that. I'm kind of inexperienced in objective-c. So, i'm gonna try to find another solution. Or i can just assume the link that is given is always correct.

Comment: Thank you Sergio. I came across the solution myself, but it is the same as yours. I accepted your answer because you had the same solution as me ;).

Answer (score 0):

try this one -

```
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
```

Comment: hi @Jack i have encountered the same problem but my problem resolved when i use ASINetworkQueue , i don't know why it works but it did.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
```

Write these two lines and then try.